# In React, how do to detect the path of the page where the user clicked on the browser's back button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frontend

User is currently on `A/B/C`. They clicked the back button of the browser to get to `A/B`. How do I detect that they user came from `A/B/C`?

Answer (score 0):

`dangerouslyGetParent` - function that returns the parent navigator.
This will give you a list of all the screens

```
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.routes
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/navigation-prop/